# I want to return a search result based on current user's data in the db django

Tags: python, django

This is my view.py

```py
def searchposts(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query= request.GET.get('q')

        submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')

        if query is not None:
            lookups= Q(suspect_name__icontains=query) | Q(complaint_name__icontains=query)

            results= CreateRecord.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

            context={'results': results,
                     'submitbutton': submitbutton}

            return render(request, 'search.html', context)

        else:
            return render(request, 'search.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'search.html')
```

The search is working but it returns a queryset that matches the query irrespective of the user. I want it to return on queryset that matches the current logged in user data in db.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
results= CreateRecord.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(lookups).distinct()
```

Django documentation [HttpRequest.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user).

> **Django uses sessions and middleware to hook the authentication system
> into request objects.**
>
> These provide a request.user attribute on every
> request which represents the current user. If the current user has not
> logged in, this attribute will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser,
> otherwise it will be an instance of User.

Comment: what i did instead is that i passed the request.user attribute as second paramete in lookups direct i.e, Q(suspect_name__icontains=query, user=request.user) and it worked! Thanks @Steven

Comment: @AdebolaAjewole You could also do that, but what if you had many Q lookups. But whatever works right.